# a single equals in an if. Javascript. Any good reason?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery.each(player, function(key, val){                     
     if (el = $("#pr_attr_plain_"+key)){
          el.text(val === "" ? 0 : " " + val);
     }
});
```

I inherited a project and I came across something strange. The guy who started the project is an expereinced programmer, definitely more so then myself.  Is there any value or reason (no matter how bad) in doing this:

```
if (el = $("#pr_attr_plain_"+key))
```

It works now and it's in a portion of the code that I don't have to touch.  I don't want to change it and have it produce unexpected consequences without knowing what it might do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can be correct.
The code is equivalent to:

```
jQuery.each(player, function(key, val){                     
     el = $("#pr_attr_plain_"+key);
     if (el){
          el.text(val === "" ? 0 : " " + val);
     }
});
```

Comment: I'll add this as a comment since no one has mentioned it. `$(..)` will ALWAYS return a jQuery object even if it doesn't match any elements. The original code snippet doesn't do what it's author thought it did. The body of the condition will always be executed, but will be a no-op anyways if `el` is empty, so it's fine. It should have been just `$("#pr..").text(...);`

Comment: Actually I did mention it :) Since there is `jQuery.each` and not `$.each` in the snippet, maybe jQuery is running in no-conflict mode?

Answer (score 3):

If the `el = $("#pr_attr_plain_"+key)` evaluates to `0` or `false` or `null` or `undefined`, it won't go inside the if-block. In all other cases it will.

Answer (score 3):

It's just an ugly way of writing

```
 el = $("#pr_attr_plain_"+key);
 if (el){
      el.text(val === "" ? 0 : " " + val);
 }
```

which is in turn the same as

```
 if ($("#pr_attr_plain_"+key)){
      $("#pr_attr_plain_"+key).text(val === "" ? 0 : " " + val);
 }
```

but slightly faster (one less call to the `$` function) and arguably easier to read. On the other hand, there are several problems with it:

- `$(something)` will never evaluate to false (it returns a jQuery object, which is truthy). Whoever wrote this probably meant `$(something).length`.
- there is no need for the whole `if`. You can just write `$("#pr_attr_plain_"+key).text(val === "" ? 0 : " " + val);` and it will have no effect if the jQuery selector does not match any element.
- unless `el` has been used previously, you should write `var el =...` not `el =` otherwise `el` will be global.
- since it is a common mistake to accidentally write `=` instead of `==`, it is advisable to either avoid assignments inside conditions or use an extra parenthesis to make it clear you were doing it deliberately:

.

```
 if ((el = $("#pr_attr_plain_"+key))){
      el.text(val === "" ? 0 : " " + val);
 }
```

Comment: Or maybe you are mixing frameworks and `$` is Prototype or something?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out on JSLint, it is a bad practice since it can also be a common mistake.  Better to fix it and reduce the chances of the wrong interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, maybe testing the `$` operator? I would *hazard* a guess that it will return false if there is an error in the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Right now this sets `el` to `$("#pr_attr_plain_"+key)`.  This tests the assignment.  This would return true unless `$()` fails, returning `null`, `false` or `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment in an `if` statement isn't that common, but it does crop up a in some languages that support it, and is often used to make code more concise.

It's usually reserved for situations where you want to assign a value to an interim variable to both test it for 'truth' and then do something else with it. So, for example:

```
if (foo = performExpensiveOperation()){
    doSomethingElse(foo); // this only happens if 'foo' is true
}
```

..is a teeny bit shorter than the alternative:

```
foo = performExpensiveOperation();
if (foo) {
    doSomethingElse(foo);
}
```

Unfortunately, Javascript doesn't allow the `var` keyword in an `if` statement (ie, `if (var foo = bar)` is a syntax error), which means you have to declare a variable up front anyway (or, worse, use a global variable).

I see it used in Perl a fair bit, too, as it also has the effect of limiting the variable to the `if`'s lexical scope. Which, again, is something Javascript can't do either (well,  support for `let` is getting there).