# Why doesn't my equality comparison using = (a single equals) work correctly?

Tags: javascript, equality

I'm trying to check if a string is blank, less than or equal to 9 digits, or up to 10 digits. But it always follows the `else if (str.length <= 9)`.

```
if (str = ''){
    console.log("The string cannot be blank");
} else if (str.length <= 9) {
    console.log("The string must be at least 9 characters long");
} else if (str.length <= 10) {
    console.log("The string is long enough.");
}
```

No matter what I put in, I always get `The string must be at least 9 characters long`. Why?

Comment: I'm sure there must be a canonical question for this...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder — Possibly, but I'd be surprised if any of them had a title as clear as this one. Mostly they come to do "My code doesn't work and I don't know why"

Comment: @Quentin: Yeah. I'm editing this into one. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder — Ooops, didn't notice that was your edit :)

Comment: @Quentin: No worries, that's a better title

Comment: There's [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3791287/a-single-equals-in-an-if-javascript-any-good-reason) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974377/how-does-the-single-equal-sign-work-in-the-if-statement-in-javascript) which are similar.

Comment: @ Sam: Your original question also did this: `if (jQuery('phone_number').length)`, which is incorrect for an unrelated reason: That's telling jQuery to look up all elements with the tag name `phone_number`. I suspect you probably meant `jQuery.trim(phone_number).length`.

Answer (score 7):

`=` is always assignment. Equality comparison is `==` (loose, coerces types to try to make a match) or `===` (no type coercion).

So you want

```
if (str === ''){
// -----^^^
```

not

```
// NOT THIS
if (str = ''){
// -----^
```

What happens when you do `if (str = '')` is that the *assignment* `str = ''` is done, and then the resulting value (`''`) is tested, effectively like this (if we ignore a couple of details):

```
str = '';
if (str) {
```

Since `''` is a *falsy* value in JavaScript, that check will be false and it goes to the `else if (str.length <= 9)` step. Since at that point, `str.length` is `0`, that's the path the code takes.