# Why doesn't my equality comparison using = (a single equals) work correctly in Java?

Tags: java, methods, return, syntax-error

I have a syntax error in the following line. However I can't understand what is the reason of this error.

```
if (address1.compareTo(address2) = 1)
        System.out.println(address1 + " is greater than " + address2);
```

What I want to achieve is printing proper message if and only if `compareTo` returns `1`.

Comment: i guess you need to look out this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Comment: Change `=` to `==` ?

Comment: should be `if (address1.compareTo(address2) == 1)`

Comment: [Different language, but exactly the same problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268329/why-doesnt-my-equality-comparison-using-a-single-equals-work-correctly)

Comment: `if (address1.compareTo(address2) > 0)` fits better the Javadoc of Comparable::compareTo

Comment: Why do you even believe that this is the correct way to compare primitive values? ***Every*** beginners book covers that topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should compare (`==`) instead of assigning (`=`). It can be very dangerous! To avoid such situations you can use `Yoda notation` so instead of comparing

```
address1.compareTo(address2) == 1
```

You can compare:

```
1 == address1.compareTo(address2)
```

In case of missing `=`, there will be comparation error.

In your case, it would be better to compare:

```
address1.compareTo(address2) > 0
```

[image]

Comment: There's never any need for Yoda notation in Java. If you're dealing with a boolean, you don't use `==` at all except in a **very** small set of use cases. If you're dealing with a non-boolean, the compiler will refuse to compile `if (foo = 42)` because you can't use an `int` (etc.) as a condition.