# Return boolean in non boolean method

Tags: java

I am trying to return False if result = false. I can't change the return type. linkList needs to return false if result = false. Thanks

```
private static class FilteringFlatApplyFunction<T> implements FlatApplyFunction<T,T> {        
    private final Predicate pred; 
    LinkedList<T> linkList = new LinkedList<T>();

    public FilteringFlatApplyFunction(Predicate<T> p) {                              
        this.pred = p;
        this.linkList = linkList;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> apply(T x){               
        boolean result = pred.check(x);              
        if (result = true) {
            linkList.add(x);
            return linkList;
        }                
        if (result = false) {
             linkList = false;              
        }               
        return linkList;                              
    }
}
```

Comment: Re `if (result = true)` and `if (result = false)`: `=` is **assignment**, not comparison; comparison is `==`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39385382/why-doesnt-my-equality-comparison-using-a-single-equals-work-correctly-in-j (Also: Don't use `==` or `!=` with booleans [partially for this reason], you already have a boolean. Just `if (result)` and `if (!result)`.)

Answer (score 6):

Quite simply, you can't.  The method signature says quite clearly that it is to return a `List<T>`, and a `List<T>` is what you shall return.

You could return `null` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return `boolean` to a `List`, what you can do is return `null`.

While you're checking the condition, what you can do is, create another method that encapsulate your `apply` method and return if you're `list` is `null` then it's false. Like below:

```
if(linkList == null)
   return false;
else
   return true;
```

Besides, Use `==` for comparison.

As below:

```
@Override
public List<T> apply(T x){               
    boolean result = pred.check(x);              
    if(result == true) {
        linkList.add(x);
        return linkList;
    }
    if(result == false){
         return null;              
    }
    return linkList;
}
```

---

OR in case of booleans you need not to use `==`, like below

```
@Override
public List<T> apply(T x){               
    boolean result = pred.check(x);              
    if(result){
        linkList.add(x);
        return linkList;
    }
    if(result){
         linkList = false;              
    }
    return linkList;
}
```

Comment: how you can assign boolean value to a List variable?

Comment: I cannot set linkList = false, it will return an error saying boolean cannot be converted to LinkedList<T>

Comment: @WasiAhmad: Updated the answer. Misunderstood initially

Answer (score 0):

You can't return false if the method specifically returns a List. What you can do is return `null':

```
@Override
public List<T> apply(T x){               
    boolean result = pred.check(x);              
    if (result == true) {
        linkList.add(x);
        return linkList;
    }
    if (result == false) {
         linkList = null;              
    }
    return linkList;
}
```

Then in the calling method do the following:

```
List<T> list = apply(x);
boolean result;
if (list == null){
   result = false;
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between your answer and @JoeC answer?

Comment: This one will always return the non-null list.

Comment: You are right Andy, it was a mistake in @Joe Van Horn' code that I copied over :) - updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry bud. You can't return different types. Returning NULL or maybe returning an object are your best chances.

Answer (score 0):

if result is false you return null so i think you dont need to do the test if result is false!!!

```
private static class FilteringFlatApplyFunction<T> implements FlatApplyFunction<T,T> {        
    private final Predicate pred; 
    LinkedList<T> linkList = new LinkedList<T>();

    public FilteringFlatApplyFunction(Predicate<T> p) {                              
        this.pred = p;
        this.linkList = linkList;
    }

    @Override
    public List<T> apply(T x){               
        boolean result = pred.check(x);              
        if (result) {
            linkList.add(x);  
        }                         
        return linkList;                              
    }
}
```