# Java Tic Tac Toe Win Detection Exiting Out Immediately After Called

Tags: java

I made this java code for win detection for the first part of my tic tac toe program. It prompts you to input a move, then immediately says "player wins." What can I do to fix this?

Main class

Runs the main loop and checks if the do-while loop is working.

```
package com.company;

public class Main {
    public static boolean gameOver = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        do {
            System.out.println("inside parent do loop");
            usrMove.main();



        }
        while (gameOver = false) ;
        System.out.println("Player wins");

    }
}
```

usrMove class

Checks if the player has won through a looping series of if else statements.

Scans the 2, 4, 5, 6 and 8 to see if there are two adjacent x's.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class usrMove {

    public static void main(){
        System.out.println("usrMove top");
        String[] board = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""}; //sets up the board with 9 empty spaces
        var scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your move:");
        var usrMove = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your move is:" + usrMove);
        for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
            if (Integer.parseInt(usrMove) == i){
                board[i] = "x"; //changes the value of the board based on user play
            }

        }
        for(int j = 2; j != 3 && j != 7; j++){ //determines if a player has won by checking if there is a piece on either side of the one being checked
            if(board[j].equals("x") && board[j - 1].equals("x") && board[j - 2].equals("x")){
                System.out.println("+-1");
            } else if(board[j + 1].equals("x") && board[j - 1].equals("x") && board[j - 3].equals("x")){
                System.out.println("+-2");
            } else if(board[j + 2].equals("x") && board[j - 1].equals("x") && board[j - 4].equals("x")){
                System.out.println("+-3");
            } else if(board[j + 3].equals("x") && board[j - 1].equals("x") && board[j - 5].equals("x")){
                System.out.println("+-4");
            } else{
                Main.gameOver = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should definitely avoid long if-statements so that the code doesn't get confusing

Comment: And you should definitely make more empty lines in your code, otherwise it will just become confusing

Comment: And why do you use Kotlin in your Java code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't my equality comparison using = (a single equals) work correctly in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39385382/why-doesnt-my-equality-comparison-using-a-single-equals-work-correctly-in-j)

Comment: After fixing the `gameOver` issued pointed out by PiRocks, every time you call `usrMove.main();` inside your loop, your `board` variable is going to be recreated and set to all blanks...you need to move that declaration out to class level and make it static.

Comment: @Verity Where do you see Kotlin getting used, the code shown is perfectly fine for Java 10 or higher (`var` was introduced in Java 10).

Answer (score 3):

`gameOver = false` should be `gameOver == false`, or `!gameOver`.

`gameOver = false` is an expression which sets `gameOver` to false and then evaluates to false, causing your do while loop to exit.

In future you can figure this kind of thing out using a debugger. You can find instructions on how to use a debugger with your editor/IDE by googling/duck-duck-going.