# Why my if & else condition doesn't work correctly?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

When I use this code to add & remove the style , Part ( else ) only works and sets (display) to block, But it will not return the class if clicked again.
what's wrong?

```
var navDropDown = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item-has-children > a');
for (let i = 0; i < navDropDown.length; i++) {
  navDropDown[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (navDropDown[i].nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none') {
      this.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      this.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Your if condition is wrong. You should do `==` instead of a single `=`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39385382/why-doesnt-my-equality-comparison-using-a-single-equals-work-correctly-in-j

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
if (navDropDown[i].nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none') {
```

uses a single `=`, instead of `==`. In Javascript, `=` is an assignment, which returns the value assigned. `'none'` being not empty, it is converted into `true`, and thus the `else` will never be executed.

Comment: This topic is ***very*** well-covered by previous questions and answers. We don't need more, just close votes (and perhaps a comment for clarity if needed).