# Can't get this select function in javascript to work

Tags: javascript, html

I think this is really easy, but I just can't get it to work.

I want my button to say different things when a different option is selected.

I tried this:

```
<select id="selector123">
  <option>test</option>
  <option>tes2</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<button onclick="test()">hoi</button>
<script>
    var e = document.getElementById("selector123");
    var strUser =
        e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    function test() {
        if (strUser =
            "test") {
            alert('this should a different text');
        } else if (strUser = "tes2") {
            alert('this should say this text');
        }
    }
</script>
```

But its not working.

Maybe know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: your if and else statements are not correct. "=" is used for assignment, if you want to compare stuff you use "=="

Comment: Another problem you have: [Why doesn't my equality comparison using = (a single equals) work correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38268329/218196)

Comment: *"But its not working."* Can you elaborate on that? What is happening and what do you expect to happen instead? Please read [ask] a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the value of `strUser` on load only, if you move it inside of the `test()` function it will update each time you click the button. You're also using the wrong comparison operator, should be `===`:

```html
<select id="selector123">
  <option>test</option>
  <option>tes2</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<button onclick="test()">hoi</button>

<script>
var e = document.getElementById("selector123");

function test() {
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    if (strUser === "test") {
        alert('this should a different text');
    } else if (strUser === "tes2") {
        alert('this should say this text');
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You got two mistakes, replace **=** with **==** and use **e.value** (optionally). **The most important thing is that the code that reads the value from the select box should be in the function!**

Also pay attention to equals "==" operator and assignment operator "="

Here is working code snippet

```html
<html> <body>
 
  <select id="selector123"> 
 <option>test</option>
 <option>tes2</option>
 </select><br><br> <button onclick="test()">hoi</button>
 
 <script> 
 
 function test(){  
 var e = document.getElementById("selector123"); 
 var strUser = e.value; 
  
  if (strUser == "test") {
         alert('this should a different text');
     }
 else if (strUser == "tes2") {
  alert('this should say this text');
   } } </script>
 
 </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use '==' to compare strings and not just '=', and also move the strUser to inside the function:

```js
var e = document.getElementById("selector123");

function test(){  
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
 if (strUser =="test") {
  alert('this should a different text');
 }else if (strUser == "tes2") {
  alert('this should say this text');
 } 
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<select id="selector123">
 <option>test</option>
 <option>tes2</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<button onclick="test()">hoi</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issues :

1: use === for comparison in if condition.

2: Declare the struser inside the click event else it will always take the value selected at the time of page load

```html
<html>

<body>

  <select id="selector123">
    <option>test</option>
    <option>tes2</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button onclick="test(event)">hoi</button>

  <script>
    var e = document.getElementById("selector123");
   

    function test(event) {
      
      var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;      
      if (strUser =="test") {
        alert('this should a different text');
      } else if (strUser == "tes2") {
        alert('this should say this text');
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```