# Change color of some words in pre tags

Tags: jquery

I am trying to display some words in specifics colors:

PASSED --> green

FAILED --> red

Until now I succeeded to display only green or red but not both in the same script. Thanks for helping me.

```
var text_change = '';

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("pre:contains('" + text_change + "')").each(function () {
    if ($text_change = 'PASSED') {
      var regex = new RegExp(text_change,'gi');
      $(this).html($(this).text().replace(regex, "<span class='green'>" + text_change + "</span>"));
    } else if ($text_change = 'FAILED') {
      var regex = new RegExp(text_change,'gi');
      $(this).html($(this).text().replace(regex, "<span class='red'>" + text_change + "</span>"));
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you please also show us the HTML

Comment: Fisrt, in your explanation you speak about 'PASSED' and 'FAILED' but in your code I see 'PASSED' and 'Result'. Is it a typing error?

Comment: See also: [*Why doesn't my equality comparison using = (a single equals) work correctly?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268329/why-doesnt-my-equality-comparison-using-a-single-equals-work-correctly) I'm afraid your question is so vague that it's unclear to me whether that's the problem or...

Comment: it's a pre tag which display a live output from redhat server

Comment: yes it's a mistake I meant FAILED

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't my equality comparison using = (a single equals) work correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268329/why-doesnt-my-equality-comparison-using-a-single-equals-work-correctly)

Comment: sorry it says : "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("pre").each(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/PASSED/g,"<span class='green'>PASSED</span>"));
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/FAILED/g,"<span class='red'>FAILED</span>"));
    });
});
```

```css
span.green{
    color:green;
}
span.red{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>PASSED FAILED PASSED FAILED</pre>
```

Comment: No problem bro.