# Shopware 6.5.4.1 Javascript remove class problem

Tags: javascript, css, shopware6

Console outputs `"Clicked Outside"`, but `show` CSS class is not removed as intended (hide dropdown on click outside):

```
var dropdownElement = document.getElementsByClassName("filter-multi-select-dropdown filter-panel-item-dropdown dropdown-menu show");

document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target = dropdownElement) {
    dropdownElement.classList.remove("show");
    console.log("Clicked Outside");
  }
});
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: Your console should *also* be showing you the error about trying to call `remove` on `undefined`, since `dropdownElement` is an `HTMLCollection`, not an element, and so doesn't have a `classList` property. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return) Separately, `=` is for *assignment*, not comparison. [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38268329/why-doesnt-my-equality-comparison-using-a-single-equals-work-correctly)

Comment: FWIW, if it's useful: https://pastebin.com/fFbHz5sy